# Half Life in EWMA time series regression

Tags: mathematical-statistics, regression, time-series

I am asked to conduct an exponential-weighted time series regression on original series $y$ and $x$ with look-back window $T$ and half life h. Denote the new series as $y^{*}$ and $x^{*}$

I am wondering what does the halflife refer to, conventionally? is it about the halflife of $y$ and $x$ $$\frac{y^{*}_{t}}{y^{*}_{t-h}} = 2$$
or the halflife of the square error in the loss function.
$$\frac{(y^{*}_{t} - \alpha - \beta * x^{*}_{t})^{2}}{(y^{*}_{t-h} - \alpha - \beta * x^{*}_{t-h})^{2}} = 2. $$

Considering a normal weighted least square regression, with $\epsilon_{i} \sim N\big(0, \frac{\sigma^{2}}{w_{I}}\big)$, I can derive that loss function
$$L = \sum_{i} w_{i} (y_{i} - \alpha - \beta * x_{i})$$ and
$$\beta^{hat} \left(\sum w_{i} x_{i}^{2} - \frac{\sum w_{i}x_{i}}{\sum w_{i}}\right) = \sum (w_{i}x_{i}y_{I}) - \frac{\sum w_{i}x_{i} \sum w_{i}y_{i}}{\sum w_{i}} $$

The formula is related to $w_{i}$. So I am confused what $w_{i}$ should be if it is derived from EWMA regression with a halflife? Thanks

Comment: It's about the half life of *T* or *y*.